# JavaFx: how to make HTMLEditor not to create emtire HTML document?

Tags: java, javafx

When javafx create object of HTMLEditor it has the empty html document with the following html:

```
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"></body></html>
```

However, I don't need entire html document. I want to work only with some node in html editor, for example with `div`.
I tried to do

```
htmlEditor.setHtmlText(null) or htmlEditor.setHtmlText("")
```

but it is ignored. When I did

```
htmlEditor.setHtmlText("<div></div>")
```

I got:

```
<html dir="ltr"><head></head><body contenteditable="true"><div></div></body></html>
```

So, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HtmlEditor` always trying to have valid html structure, that is why it adds tags.

You need DOM manipulation library, for example [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/). Or manage DOM transition before sending to render, when applying string to editor.